# JQuery lt selector with class and attribute

Tags: jquery, filter

Please avoid poor English.

I want to apply jQuery 'lt' and 'gt' selector on class with his attribute.

I have a class 'filter' with attribute 'value' and I want to select only element whose value is less than 25. I do following way but it was not work.

```
$(".filter[value:lt('25')]").length;
```

and my element as

```
<tr class="filter" value="25" name="something1">
<tr class="filter" value="24" name="something2">
<tr class="filter" value="26" name="something3">
<tr class="filter" value="23" name="something4">
```

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: You can not lt & gt for `value`. defination for it is $(":lt(index)") for index only.

Comment: Use `$('tr.filter').filter(function() {
    return +$(this).attr('value') < 25;
}).length;` [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pmsq5qb4/1/)

Comment: thanks Tushar and parth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop) like below:

```
$(".filter").filter(function(){
  return parseInt($(this).prop('value'), 10) < 25;
}).length;
```

---

:lt or :gt selector is to select elements with lesser or greater index not for attributes values.

---

I have updated the @tushar demo provided in comment so you don't need to use parseInt as prop method returns the number as I commented before:

```
//So, just use:
return $(this).prop('value') < 25;
//Instead of
return parseInt($(this).prop('value'), 10) < 25;
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pmsq5qb4/2/)

Comment: Thanks Bhojendra, what is 10 indicate in parseInt

Comment: It is base in which to parse. So, 10 is decimal.

Comment: Why you need `[]` in `prop`? you can use `.attr('value')`

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help.